# Why did UITextView show different size of NSAttributedString and line height?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just adjust the order of characters which is symbols(▲, ●, ■).The size of character is related to symbols which one is first.

> ▲●■▲●■▲●■*asdf
>
> ●▲■▲●■▲●■*asdf
>
> ■●■▲●■▲●■*asdf

UITextView shows wrong size of character.

[The wrong size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4vww.png)

This wrong size have an effect on size of words(no attribute) that is after first symbols(▲, ●, ■).

```
NSMutableAttributedString *symbol = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"■▲●■▲●■▲●■*asdf"];
UIFont *symbolFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];
UIColor *stripesPurple = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.83 green:0.64 blue:0.83 alpha:1];


[symbol addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor purpleColor],
                        NSFontAttributeName:symbolFont,
                        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@-4,
                        NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor purpleColor]}
                range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
[symbol addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:stripesPurple,
                        NSFontAttributeName:symbolFont,
                        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@-4,
                        NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor purpleColor]}
                range:NSMakeRange(3, 3)];
[symbol addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                        NSFontAttributeName:symbolFont,
                        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@-4,
                        NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor purpleColor]}
                range:NSMakeRange(6, 3)];
[self.myTextView setAttributedText:symbol];
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using UITextView? Why not try UILabel with number of lines as 0 which will auto adjust height for text

Comment: @aman.sood The line height worked good with UILabel.However, The size of first "●" is still wrong.(smaller than others).

Comment: rather then taking single label take three of them and align one after the other vertically without fixing height in xib.

Comment: This code is for learning, so I would prefer knowing the cause.

Comment: ok then will try at my end as well. Will update you

Comment: What i can make out of it is if dot comes first then UITextView is treating as a bullet rather than a simple character.

Comment: @aman.sood Bullet is a key to understand why the size of first dot is wrong. Thanks a lot! Could you tell me how to find out that dot is a bullet?